# Wordpress - Zip archive force download

Tags: php, wordpress, zip, archive

I am trying to give the possiblity to an user to download an archive in wordpress, but the download don't start after the creation of the archive. I can see that my archive is created, she's available on the server. Here my code :

My "library"

```
<?php
    function create_zip($files = array(), $destination = '', $overwrite = false) {
        if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) {
            return false;
        }
        $valid_files = array();
        if(is_array($files)) {
            foreach($files as $file) {
                if(file_exists($file)) {
                    $valid_files[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        if(count($valid_files)) {
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
                return false;
            }
            foreach($valid_files as $file) {
                $zip->addFile($file,$file);
            }
            $zip->close();
            return file_exists($destination);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

?>
```

The function called by wordpress :

```
<?php

    require "zip.php";
    $customwp = plugins_url().'/customwp/';
    wp_enqueue_style('tutoriels',$customwp.'css/tutoriels.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('tutoriels',$customwp.'js/tutoriels.js',array('jquery'),'1.0',true);

    ob_start();

    $dir = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/customwp/';
    $files_to_zip = array(
        $dir.'zip.php'
    );
    $archive_name = "archive.zip";
    $result = create_zip($files_to_zip, $archive_name);

    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); //Transfert en binaire (fichier).
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="archive.zip"'); //Nom du fichier.
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archive_name)); //Taille du fichier.
    readfile($archive_name);

    $output_string=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output_string;

?>
```

If you can help me, don't hesitate to try !
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

the final line, where you have

```
return $output_string;
```

it should be

```
echo $output_string;
```

also, although in this case it seems it doesn't affect your code, but keep in mind that output buffering doesn't buffer your header() calls, they are sent immediately. See the [php page about it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

> This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script **(other than headers)**, instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.

Comment: Arf yes I forgot that, so do you see a solution, what I want it's to be able to call my function in a shortcode :/. It's why I use the ouput buffering. Even with the echo the archive is not send.